# Stored Procedure for upgrading Bags to Lists

Tags: sql, hibernate, stored-procedures, postgresql-9.1, plpgsql

I just recently changed the semantics of some some hibernate mapped classes to lists. Adding the list index column itself is trivial, but populating it in a sensible way seemed less trivial. I wound up writing the following stored procedure (PL/pgsql), which works by looping through all the rows of a table ordered by the reference column and setting the indexes to 0, 1, 2, 3 etc until a new reference number is found. It solved the problem but I wonder if there is a simpler way to achieve the same result.

```sql
  CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION setlistorderfunc(VARCHAR, VARCHAR) RETURNS VOID AS $$
  DECLARE
    currIndex INTEGER := 0;
    currResource INTEGER := 0;
    r RECORD;
  BEGIN
    FOR r IN execute 'SELECT id id, '|| $2 || ' res, resource_list_order rlo FROM ' || $1 || ' ORDER BY res ASC, rlo ASC' LOOP
      IF currResource != r.res THEN
        currResource := r.res;
        currIndex := 0;
      ELSE
        currIndex := currIndex + 1;
      END IF;
      EXECUTE 'UPDATE ' || $1 || ' set resource_list_order = ' || currIndex || 'WHERE id = ' || r.id;
    END LOOP;
  END;
  $$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

To upgrade a bag of `rating`s on a resource (linked by a column named `about_resource`) I then do this:

```
  SELECT setlistorderfunc('rating', 'about_resource');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [window function **`row_number()`**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-window.html) in a subquery, and join to the result in the [`UPDATE`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-update.html) to largely simplify this:

```
UPDATE rating r
SET    resource_list_order = sub.rn
FROM  (
    SELECT id, row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY about_resource
                                  ORDER BY resource_list_order) - 1 AS rn
    FROM   rating
    ) sub
WHERE  r.id = sub.id;
```